# Filter an array of strings based on contents of array itself

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

How can I remove all substrings of another string within an array of strings? I want this array of strings:

```
arr = ["Bochum", "Stu", "Stut", "Stuttt", "Stutt", "Stuttgart", "Heesestr.", "Berl", "Berlin"]
```

to shrink to:

```
["Bochum", "Stuttt", "Stuttgart", "Heesestr.", "Berlin"]
```

Edit:

- Order does not need to be preserved. Sorting the elements is fine, if it helps.
- Assume `arr` is unique, with no dups.

Comment: What if the array included `ochu`? A small suggestion: when you give examples, assign a variable to each input object (e.g, `arr = ["Bochum", ...]`). That way readers can refer to those variables (e.g., `arr`) in comments and answers without having to define them.

Comment: When you edit your question after an answer has been posted it's best to leave what you had and add to it, making clear that it is an edit (e.g., "Edit: ..."). If you don't do that you may render answers or comments incorrect or meaningless. btw, you didn't answer my question re `ochu`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### One-Liner with Sort, Grep, and Count

Assuming your array elements always *start* with the same letters, one way to remove substrings is to sort, which will place shorter elements first. You can then reject elements that have longer matches deeper into the array. For example:

```
array = %w[Bochum Stu Stut Stuttt Stutt Stuttgart Heesestr. Berl Berlin]
array.sort.reject { |elem| array.grep(/\A#{elem}/).count > 1 }
#=> ["Berlin", "Bochum", "Heesestr.", "Stuttgart", "Stuttt"]
```

If your array shouldn't be sorted, then this is not the right solution for you. However, it definitely contains the right array elements, and is both short and easy to read. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: A possible edge problem: if `arr = ["Stu", "Stu"]` it returns an empty array. I say "possible" because I don't know what the OP wants in this case or even  permits dups.

Comment: A tiny tweak to your response, got me to what I've decided to go with: `array.sort.select { |elem| array.grep(/\A#{elem}/).one? }`

Answer (score 2):

If you're not opposed to the use of brute force:

```
arr = ["Bochum", "Stu", "Stut", "Stuttt", "Stutt", "Stuttgart",
       "Heesestr.", "Berl", "Berlin"]

arr.each_with_object([]) { |str,a|
  a << str unless arr.any? { |s| s.include?(str) && s.size > str.size } }
  #=> ["Bochum", "Stuttt", "Stuttgart", "Heesestr.", "Berlin"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation using a Trie-like data structure. It achieves the goal by simply losing information :-)

(I've assumed you only care about strings being *prefixes* of each other, rather than substrings...)

```
class LossyTrie
  def initialize; @dict = {}; end

  def add(str)
    # Break the new string apart into characters, traversing down the trie at each step.
    # As a side effect, if a prefix of str was already present, it will be forgotten.
    # Similarly, if str itself is a prefix of an existing string, nothing will change.
    dict = @dict
    str.each_char do |c|
      dict = (dict[c] ||= {})
    end
  end

  def all_strings
    strs = []
    def traverse(dict, so_far, &block)
      for k, v in dict
        if v.empty?
          block.call(so_far + k)
        else
          traverse(v, so_far + k, &block)
        end
      end
    end
    traverse(@dict, "") { |leaf| strs << leaf }
    strs
  end
end

strs = ["Bochum", "Stu", "Stut", "Stuttt", "Stutt", "Stuttgart", "Heesestr.", "Berl", "Berlin"]

trie = LossyTrie.new
strs.each { |s| trie.add(s) }

trie.all_strings # => ["Bochum", "Berlin", "Stuttt", "Stuttgart", "Heesestr."]
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for Rails, plain Ruby will do:

```
my_array =["Bochum", "Stu", "Stut", "Stuttt", "Stutt", "Stuttgart", "Heesestr.", "Berl", "Berlin"]

my_array.keep_if {|x| my_array.join(",").scan(x).length == 1}
```

Comment: yes, that should be `my_array`.  Was trying to clean up variable names, and left one out...  sorry..

Answer (score 0):

A solution that does not preserve the order:

```
["Bochum", "Stu", "Stut", "Stuttt", "Stutt", "Stuttgart",
   "Heesestr.", "Berlin", "Berl"].sort_by(&:size).reduce([]) do |ary, word|
  ary.reject{|s| word.include?(s)}.push(word)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the sub-strings and remove them, might be not good but clear

```
ar = ["Bochum", "Stu", "Stut", "Stuttt", "Stutt", "Stuttgart", "Heesestr.", "Berl", "Berlin"] 
sub_strings = []
ar.collect do |string|
  for index in 0...string.length
    sub_strings << string[0...index] if ar.include?(string[0...index]) 
  end
end
results = ar - sub_strings
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank you! haha just too many Objective C code due to it.